# Redirect www2 to another server

Tags: domain-name-system

I need redirect `www2` subdomain existent on `example.com` (192.0.2.1) to redirect transparently to another server (like `example.net`, 192.0.2.2). But I'll access this second server via `www2.example.com`. How I can do that?

Currently I tried create the `CNAME` and/or `A` entries on `example.com` like `"www2 CNAME example.net"` and `www2 A example.net`, and I setup on `example.net` this entries too, but it doesn't worked.

**EDIT**: this is my current setting.

**example.com** (main server):

```
    www  A     192.0.2.1
    www2 CNAME parked.example.net
```

**example.net** (secondary server): I have two domains configured on this server. I don't know how I need configure it. But basically I have `example.com` (the same name of main site) and a parked domain called `parked.example.net`. I tried configured this on both, but nothing worked.

```
    www2 A     192.0.2.2
```

Currently, the `www2.example.com` is redirecting to secondary server, but it not handle it correctly to website installed on it, returning a "Sorry" message from cgi if I access it directly, like `http://www2.example.com/`. Or returning a "404 Error" (aqua screen) if I access it like `http://www2.example.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
example.com
   WWW  A 192.0.2.1
   WWW2 CNAME WWW2.example.net.
example.net
   WWW2 A 192.0.2.2
```

This will make `www.example.com` go to 192.0.2.1, while `www2.example.com` will go to 192.0.2.2.

Comment: How I need to configure the `www2` on `example.net`? I need do it directly on domain root? Or can I use a parked domain like `parked.example.net` configured on `example.net`?

Comment: Configure it in what, DNS or your web server?  This is dependent on who you're configuring it with.  If you're using some tool from a domain host, only they can answer.

Comment: I have access to DNS Zone Editor on both servers.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Sure, that works, give it a try. The problem seems to be more an issue of the config on the server part of example.net, which we can't help with as it's cPanel.

Comment: Now it work with small changes. First I removed the parked domain (parked.example.net), and renamed the original name (on example.net) of example.com to parked.example.net. After I parked (via Park Domain) the www2.example.com. And it work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First off, give us more information on what's not working.  Are you getting the website for www2.example.com?  A DNS error?  404 Page?  something completely different?

Some things to check on:  Make sure DNS is resolving properly.  You may need to clear your cache.  Ping www2.example.com, and make sure you're getting the correct IP address.

Otherwise, your question hints that you might be attempting to do this with websites.  Is the site at example.net configured to respond to requests for www2.example.com?  If not, you might want a http redirect at www2.example.com, instead of the DNS method you're attempting here.

Comment: My current setting is `example.com` (main) `www2 CNAME example.net` (secondary), `example.net` (secondary) `www2 A 192.0.2.2`. Seems that main server is redirecting to secondary server (because the response IP is `192.0.2.2`), but I getting a "Sorry" page (`cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`).

Comment: If you're getting the right IP address, then DNS is working properly.  It would appear that you need to configure your website to accept connections for www2.example.com.

Comment: I have only a simple page to test. My website do not check subdomain. I think that I need setup my secondary server to redirect correctly to local website.

Comment: I edited my post.